# Gridview.builder start at the end of list

Tags: flutter, gridview, scrollcontroller

I have a Gridview.builder in a Widget. When I open the widget I would like to jump immediately to the end of the Grid List.

```
class _StampsInTravelbookState extends State<StampsInTravelbook> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
      _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
    }
    return GridView.builder(
      controller: _scrollController,
      reverse: false,
      itemCount:
          Provider.of<UserPosProv>(context, listen: true).userStamps.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
```

But I always have the Grid at the beginning.

When I set

> reverse: true

the Grid shows the end of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `userStamps.reverse()`

**Example**

```
class _StampsInTravelbookState extends State<StampsInTravelbook> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userStamps = Provider.of<UserPosProv>(context, listen: true).userStamps;
    userStamps.reverse(); // This line makes your userStamps list reversed.
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: userStamps.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => // Your GridTile here,
      shrinkWrap: true,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx, this works!!!

I had to change it slightly:
Provider.of<UserPosProv>(context, listen: true)
          .userStamps
          .reversed
          .toList()

Answer (score 1):

i think this will work for you

```
 _scrollController.animateTo(
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
``
```